# BigQuery: UNNEST result containing multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a UDF which returns multiple rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dataset.multi_row() RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<r1 FLOAT64, r2 FLOAT64>> LANGUAGE js AS """
  return [{
    "r1": 10 * Math.random(),
    "r2": 10 * Math.random()
  }, {
    "r1": 100 * Math.random(),
    "r2": 100 * Math.random()
  }]
""";
```

Lets say this UDF is used in a query which produces multiple rows, e.g

```
SELECT dataset.multi_row() FROM UNNEST([1,2,3])

Row   f0_.r1              f0_.r2
---   -----------------   -----------------
1     9.328970861925416   9.61853335054045
      20.700051452811017  87.67054242459575
2     4.184274373335275   6.136918172331227
      26.790853709322747  35.848885881352
3     0.32172810017527365 7.416528380222973
      70.21210223299556   57.644422256839746
```

I would like to convert each row and array entry into a separate row so it looks like this:

```
Row   f0_.r1              f0_.r2
---   -----------------   -----------------
1     9.328970861925416   9.61853335054045
2     20.700051452811017  87.67054242459575
3     4.184274373335275   6.136918172331227
4     26.790853709322747  35.848885881352
5     0.32172810017527365 7.416528380222973
6     70.21210223299556   57.644422256839746
```

What does the SQL query look like to produce this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving data on BQ temp table, then following code it will `unnest` data

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT
   [9.328970861925416, 20.700051452811017] as col_1,
   [9.61853335054045, 87.67054242459575] as col_2 union all
SELECT
   [4.184274373335275, 26.790853709322747] as col_1,
   [6.136918172331227, 35.848885881352] as col_2 union all
SELECT
   [0.32172810017527365, 70.21210223299556] as col_1,
   [7.416528380222973, 57.644422256839746] as col_2 
) 

SELECT col_1, col_2[OFFSET(off)] as col_2 FROM data ,unnest(col_1) as col_1 WITH OFFSET off
```

Output will as :-

[image]

Comment: My question was aiming at a more general case. For instance, the number of rows that the UDF function returns can be upwards 100 (in my example I kept it purposefully simple with only 2 rows). Furthermore, the number of rows that the SQL query might return is also dynamic (upwards maybe 1000). Your solution is too tailor made for my concrete example, I want something that works in the general case.

Comment: ```UNNEST``` function is not possible at Function level, you need to think over solution in parts, First loading of data to some intermediate place holder and then getting data to UNNEST. My solution cloud be a potential indicator in same direction. Possible solution cloud be 'Dataflow' pipeline or some scheduled BQ queries based on Number of Fields in Temp (or Intermediate) table to UNNEST data.